# Transforming flat lists into nested lists

Tags: xslt

I have some XML which describe books as follows:

```
<root>
    <chapter>
        <chapter_number>some chapter</chapter_number>
        <chapter_title>some title</chapter_title>

        <heading_1>some heading</heading_1>

        <para>some plain text <italic>some italic text</italic> some more text</para>

        <list_1_letter>item 1</list_1_letter>
        <list_1_letter>item 2</list_1_letter>
        <list_2_bullet>sub-item 1</list_2_bullet>
        <list_2_bullet>sub-item 2</list_2_bullet>
        <list_1_letter>item 3</list_1_letter>

        <para>some other text</para>

        <list_1_number>item 1</list_1_number>
        <list_2_roman>sub-item 1</list_2_roman>
        <list_2_roman>sub-item 2</list_2_roman>
        <list_1_number>item 2</list_1_number>
        <list_2_roman>sub-item 3</list_2_roman>
        <list_2_roman>sub-item 4</list_2_roman>
    </chapter>
</root>
```

The lists need to be wrapped in an element which describes them, but the sub-lists should be children of the list above them. In this case, the desired output would be:

```
<root>
    <chapter>
        <chapter_number>some chapter</chapter_number>
        <chapter_title>some title</chapter_title>

        <heading_1>some heading</heading_1>

        <para>some plain text <italic>some italic text</italic> some more text</para>

        <letter_list>
            <list_1_letter>item 1</list_1_letter>
            <list_1_letter>item 2</list_1_letter>
            <bullet_list>
                <list_2_bullet>sub-item 1</list_2_bullet>
                <list_2_bullet>sub-item 2</list_2_bullet>
            </bullet_list>
            <list_1_letter>item 3</list_1_letter>
        </letter_list>

        <para>some other text</para>

        <number_list>
            <list_1_number>item 1</list_1_number>
            <roman_list>
                <list_2_roman>sub-item 1</list_2_roman>
                <list_2_roman>sub-item 2</list_2_roman>
            </roman_list>
            <list_1_number>item 2</list_1_number>
            <roman_list>
                <list_2_roman>sub-item 3</list_2_roman>
                <list_2_roman>sub-item 4</list_2_roman>
            </roman_list>
        </number_list>
    </chapter>
</root>
```

Adapting some other answers from here I can wrap the lists but I can only wrap sequences of the same list, it will produce:

```
<number_list>
    <list_1_number>item 1</list_1_number>
</number_list>
<roman_list>
    <list_2_roman>sub-item 1</list_2_roman>
    <list_2_roman>sub-item 2</list_2_roman>
</roman_list>
<number_list>
    <list_1_number>item 2</list_1_number>
</number_list>
<roman_list>
    <list_2_roman>sub-item 3</list_2_roman>
    <list_2_roman>sub-item 4</list_2_roman>
</roman_list>
```

Not quite what I'm after! This is proving far tricker than I had expected when taking this on.

Comment: At first you have to find a rule you can explain. At least I do not see why bullet_list is child of letter_list but number_list is not.

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0 or are you limited to 1.0?

Comment: @IanRoberts I can use XSLT 2.0. @hr_117 number_list is not a child of letter_list because it is a completely separate list? The number in the tag denotes it's level. `list_1` is a top-level list, `list_2` is a sub-list within the `list_1`.

Comment: It is very tricky, and maybe XSLT isn't the best language to use for this.  I can visualise a part solution using `for-each-group` and `group-starting-with`, but the condition for finding the start of a list is not nice.  Obviously a `list_1_X` preceded by something that's not a `list_*` is the start of a list, but I presume you also need to spot a `list_1_X` immediately followed by a `list_1_Y` as being two separate lists, and that's where my brain started to melt...  It would be so much easier in an imperative language with updateable variables.

Comment: I was hoping for an XSLT solution but I'll give it a go in Python using lxml or something, I have more experience there anyway.

Comment: The other problem I see is knowing if a list is the child or sibling of a previous list. The `list_n_` part really only says the level, and doesn't necessarily imply a hierarchy.
For example, `list_2_letter` followed by `list_1_bullet` could mean that bullet is a part of the hierarchy that contains the letter list, or it could be the start of an entirely new list.
Without additional rules it very difficult to capture what you need algorithmically.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="starts-with(name(),'list')">
   <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
     <xsl:element name="{replace(name(),'.*_.*_','')}_list">
      <xsl:variable name="thislist" select="name()"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-adjacent="name()">
       <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="name()=$thislist">
     <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:element name="{replace(name(),'.*_.*_','')}_list">
     <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
     </xsl:element>
    </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
     </xsl:element>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces

```
<root>
   <chapter>
      <chapter_number>some chapter</chapter_number>
      <chapter_title>some title</chapter_title>
      <heading_1>some heading</heading_1>
      <para>some plain text <italic>some italic text</italic> some more text</para>
      <letter_list>
         <list_1_letter>item 1</list_1_letter>
         <list_1_letter>item 2</list_1_letter>
         <bullet_list>
            <list_2_bullet>sub-item 1</list_2_bullet>
            <list_2_bullet>sub-item 2</list_2_bullet>
         </bullet_list>
         <list_1_letter>item 3</list_1_letter>
      </letter_list>
      <para>some other text</para>
      <number_list>
         <list_1_number>item 1</list_1_number>
         <roman_list>
            <list_2_roman>sub-item 1</list_2_roman>
            <list_2_roman>sub-item 2</list_2_roman>
         </roman_list>
         <list_1_number>item 2</list_1_number>
         <roman_list>
            <list_2_roman>sub-item 3</list_2_roman>
            <list_2_roman>sub-item 4</list_2_roman>
         </roman_list>
      </number_list>
   </chapter>
</root>
```